# git ignore called folders and exclude a particular file in a folder

Tags: git

I'm trying to push some files to my repo and ignore some folders but i want want just one file in a sub folder and exclude all files in that sub folder with exception of just one file. The folder structure is like

```
Apps->Features->username.php
```

Apps is the main folder and has other sub folders, features is a sub-folder and username.php is a file in it with and files.
So what i want to achieve is to exclude all files in the features folder with exception of username.php

Comment: On one line `Apps/Features/*`, on the **next** line `!Apps/Features/username.php`

Answer (score 0):

```
Apps/*
!Apps/Features
Apps/Features/*
!Apps/Features/username.php
```

See if this works. Since you mentioned /Apps/ has some other subfolders, make sure to add `!Apps/foo` for each additional subfolder you want to include.